# AES encryption algorithm, paralel programming,java

Tags: java, aes

I have a project that write with a friend and we're in trouble with threads. code select a file, encrypt or decrypt it and write it a file(every file pdf,docx,mpeg,mkv,etc.).

selected,opened with RandomAccessFile an input and output object,

```
byte[] temp new byte[16];
readedByte=1;
while(16*readedByte<fileLenght){
                for(i=0;i<16;i++){
                temp[i]=input.readByte();
                }
                byte[] newTemp=AES.encrypt(temp, k.getBytes("ISO-8859-9"));
                output.write(newTemp);
                readedByte++;
            }
```

i want to write a thread that do this job. thread will read 16 byte, encrypt them and write to output object.

Comment: Why do you want to write an explicit thread to do this job? Is it so you don't block the UI?

Comment: actually a have to write a thread and i think this way is easiest because of it has read file and write to file. if you think better way than it i listen you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your method inside of run. and try to adapt it to address your issue

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                byte[] temp = new byte[16];
                int readedByte = 1;
                while(16 * readedByte < fileLenght) {

                    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                        temp[i] = input.readByte();
                    }
                    byte[] newTemp = AES.encrypt(temp, k.getBytes("ISO-8859-9"));
                    output.write(newTemp);
                    readedByte++;
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();
```

Comment: where are input and output? i could open and close files at every thread but it wasn't a good for performance

Comment: just do it outside the thread and passe what ever you want to check  as variable in the thread

Comment: You will not give the parameter direct to thread but just declare it as class variable and you can passe it wherever you need it